# Using data between any controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have spent hours trying to use a set a tableViewCell from a picker selection in another view. I have posted two questions, that brought no answers. So i decided to approach it differently. I tired making a global variable, but then figured out, I had to make a dataClass file which wouldn't work for me because I have to use a viewController. Im beginning to lose hope. Is their any way to set the title of a table view cell from another view? Im not looking for a giant chunk of code, just a place to start. The way to actually do it, if its possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to select a `UITableViewCell` based on the value of a `UIPickerView` contained within a `UIView` of the same `UIViewController`? Or do you want to change, for example, a `UILabel` within a `UITableViewCell` based on the `UIPickerView` selected value??

Comment: Right now, I have a tableView. That when a button is pressed a new table cell comes up. I can tap the cell and a  view come up and their is a picker in the view with some names. I want the selected item in the picker to be the name of the tableViewCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. In Model-View-Controller systems all information sharing happens through your model class. Make it a singleton object (singleton is similar to global variables, but it has proper initialization).

Create a class with the data that must be shared. Create a class method of that class to produce the sole instance of that class. Define and initialize a static variable holding that instance. Use `dispatch_once` to initialize that instance. [Here is an answer illustrating this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11945106/335858).

With a singleton instance in place, all your view controllers can access the model as necessary. One view controller can set properties of the model, so that when the other view controller comes along, the data is ready for it to process.

Comment: New to objective C and this area especially. Plus im 13, but anyway, I dont really understand what a modalViewController is. And can I use my existing viewcontroller with the picker? Or do I need to make a new file?

Comment: @user2660874 [Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html) is a way to structure your program to separate the code that defines how your program looks (the view) from the code that defines what your program does (the controller) and the data that it needs to do it (the model). Check the answer I linked - you'll need to add two new files (Model.h and Model.m). Replace the `session` property from that answer with a `title` string property, and use that property from anywhere in your code.

Comment: What subclass do I make it under?

Comment: @user2660874 What do you mean by "what subclass"? Model is a separate independent class: in Xcode, right-click your project, choose "New File...", select "Objective-C class", call it "Model", and add the code from the other answer that I linked above.

Comment: I tried putting this in [[Modal instance].session connect];
    [[Modal instance].session sendAction:myAction]; and I got the error use of undeclared Identifier model

Comment: whoope, didnt import model.h

Comment: I ended up using an array in to fill the picker. I have made one in the modelViewController and now what. Hoe can I use this in another view controller?

Comment: @user2660874 Add an `NSArray` property to the `Model` - say, `pickerData`. Set that property inside the view controller that provides the data, like this: `[Model instance].pickerData = /*your array data goes here*/`. Then use `[Model instance].pickerData` in all places where you want to access the picker data array. Don't forget to import `Model.h`, and everything should work.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but where do I add the nsarray? What should I change in the example you gave me?

Comment: @user2660874 `@property (nonatomic, readwrite) Session *session;` should become `@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSArray *pickerData;`

Comment: but where would I put `[Model instance].pickerData = /*your array data goes here*/`?

Comment: Ok I think I got it working, but now I put this code `self.Picker = [Model instance].pickerData;` in a viewController and now when a tableViewCell is selected, it turns blue and the app freezes

Comment: @user2660874 Don't try to follow this blindly, try to understand what is going on. You have two view controllers that need to talk. One view controller needs to set something (I thought it was an array, but it could be anything at all). The other view controller needs to read that something. Whatever that "something" may be, make it a property of the `Model`, set it in the view controller that provides the data, and get it in the view controller that consumes the data.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I still dont know if I am setting the pproperty for the nsarray

Comment: Where do I set the property?

Comment: @user2660874 Set it in the picker's delegate `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`. The array should have as many items as the components in the picker - one element per component selection. Let's say your picker has two components - size `S,M,L,XL` and color `Red,Green,White`. Then `NSArray` should have two elements. If there's only one component, change `NSArray *pickerData` to `NSString *pickerData`, and set `[Model instance].pickerData = pickerSourceArray[row]` inside the `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` method.