# Parsing a local xml file and presenting the data in a table view

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse a simple xml file which I created.

I read through a bunch of tutorials regarding this subject and still I can't get the information to display on the simulator (I keep getting an empty list).

My xml file:
    
    
    
    Title of first book
    Name one
    
    
    Title of second book
    Name two

My code:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *xmlPath = [ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource : @" Books.xml "       ofType:@"xml" ] ;
    NSData *xmlData = [ NSData dataWithContentsOfFile : xmlPath ] ;
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [ [ NSXMLParser alloc ] initWithData:xmlData ] ;
    XMLParser *parser = [ [ XMLParser alloc ] initXMLParser ] ;
   [ xmlParser setDelegate : parser ] ;
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
if ( success )
    NSLog ( @" amount %i ", [ books count ] ) ;
else
    NSLog(@"Error!!!");
    return YES;
}

@implementation XMLParser

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser
{
    self = [ super init ] ;
    appDelegate = ( AppDelegate * ) [ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] delegate ] ;
    return self ;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ( [ elementName isEqualToString : @" Books " ] )
{
appDelegate.books = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ] ;
}
else if ( [ elementName isEqualToString : @" Book " ] )
{
aBook = [ [ Book alloc ] init ] ;
aBook.bookID = [ [ attributeDict objectForKey : @" id " ] integerValue ] ;
NSLog(@"Reading id value :%i", aBook.bookID);
    }
    else if ( [ elementName isEqualToString : @" title " ] )
    {
        aBook.title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
   }
    else if ( [ elementName isEqualToString : @" author " ] )
    { 
        aBook.author = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    NSLog ( @" Processing Element : %@", elementName ) ;
}

- ( void ) parser : ( NSXMLParser * ) parser foundCharacters : ( NSString * ) string
{   
    if ( !currentElementValue )
    {
    currentElementValue = [ [ NSMutableString alloc ] initWithString : string ] ;
    }
    else
    {
    [ currentElementValue appendString : string ] ;
    }
    NSLog ( @" Processing Value : %@ ", currentElementValue ) ;
}

- ( void ) parser : ( NSXMLParser * ) parser didEndElement : ( NSString * ) elementName
namespaceURI : ( NSString * ) namespaceURI qualifiedName : ( NSString * ) qName

{   
    if ( [ elementName isEqualToString : @" Books " ] )
    return;
    if ( [ elementName isEqualToString : @" Book " ] )
    {
    [ appDelegate.books addObject : aBook ] ;
        aBook = nil ;
    }
    else
    {
    [ aBook setValue : currentElementValue forKey : elementName ] ;
    }
    currentElementValue = nil ;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

    - (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- ( void ) viewDidLoad
{
    [ super viewDidLoad ] ;
    appDelegate = ( AppDelegate * ) [ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] delegate ]     ;
    self.title = @" Books ";    
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [ appDelegate.books count ] ;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"         forIndexPath:indexPath];
    aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = aBook.title;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
       // [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

@end
```

can anyone help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using your appdelegate for a "dumping ground" of global variables is a poor design choice. Define and use a separate model class; add a singleton for it (here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11945106/335858) explaining how to do it).

Comment: Not that you shouldn't learn how to parse XML, but any reason you can't use a plist?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, first of all, thank you for the help but I didn't understand exactly how to utilise what you suggested.
can't the code work using the appDelegate?

Comment: @user1868558 `AppDelegate` class should be "as empty as possible". Read about MVC (model-view-controller) pattern, you will be using it a lot in iOS programming. The model in your implementation is dumped into app delegate. This is incorrect. Make your model a separate class. To ensure universal access to your model, make it a singleton.

Comment: @Wain, also thank you. As I mentioned, I'm just starting to learn ios programming and i'm not familiar with plist. Besides, at the moment i'm specifically trying to learn how to parse xml files

Answer (score 1):

You almost always seem to add a leading and trailing space to your strings. I doubt that this is what you want.

You also do this for the file path and you add the .xml extension to the resource name, which you shouldn't do when using `pathForResource:ofType:`.

Assuming that your file is named 'Books.xml' use this to retrieve the path to your XML file:

```
NSString *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource : @"Books" ofType:@"xml"];
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, the list on the simulator is still empty but now I can see the file is being parsed.
someone told me to add spaces to make the code more readable, which I think I'll stop doing from now on.
I can see in the output in Xcode that the elements from the xml file are being read, only I can't see anything on the simulator. Do you have on suggestions on where could the problem be?