# How to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with sectioned UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have been implementing a app with sectioned UITableView. In the tableview, I used a array, called sections, to store different classes array and show them in different sections. On the other hand, I also used a array, called headers, to store section headers' name. For example, in the "weekday" section, there are seven words, Sunday to Saturday, in the tableViewCell under this section. In the MainViewController:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *weekday=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *traffic=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSArray *sec_ary in listData) {
    NSString *class=[[sec_ary valueForKey:@"vocabulary_list"]valueForKey:@"Class"];
    if ([class isEqualToString:@"WEEKDAY"]) {
       [weekday addObject:[[sec_ary valueForKey:@"vocabulary_list"]valueForKey:@"Vocabulary"]];
    }else if ([class isEqualToString:@"TRAFFIC TOOLS"]){
        [traffic addObject:[[sec_ary valueForKey:@"vocabulary_list"]valueForKey:@"Vocabulary"]];
    }
    sections=[[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:weekday,traffic,nil];
    headers=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"WEEKDAY",@"TRAFFIC TOOLS",nil];
}
```

In this App, I also implemented the navigation controller, which can bring user to view detail information in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. The codes are following

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
      ContentViewController *content= [[ContentViewController alloc] initwithIndexPath:indexPath];
      [delegate.navController1 pushViewController:content animated:YES];
      [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];  
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
      static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"tableidentifier"; / 
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier]; 

      if (cell == nil) { 
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle          reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier] autorelease];
      } 
      cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[[self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

      return cell; 
}
```

In the ContentViewController:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
      NSDictionary *voc_list=[delegate.vcblr objectAtIndex:index.row];
      //extracting the voc_list dictionary to show infomation.....
}
```

I am wondering why each section will load the information from beginning in the voc_list. That is to say, the tableViewCell do not respond to the right detail content. Could anyone provide me with ideas to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering why each section will load the information from beginning in the `voc_list`.

Because the code of your `viewDidLoad` method ignores `index.section`, paying attention to `index.row` alone. You need to decide on the index that you pass to `delegate.vcblr` based on both the `section` and the `row`; the exact calculation depends on the structure of your data, i.e. how many rows you have in each section.

**Note :** Using `AppDelegate` to share data among view controllers is not a good idea. Consider separating out your data in a separate model class, [and make that class a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11945106/335858).

Comment: Could you please instruct me how to use the index.section method in the viewDidLoad in ContentViewController and how to decide index of delegate.vcblr to section?
I try to modify my code like following: 
`NSDictionary *voc_list=[[delegate.vcblr objectAtIndex:index.section]objectAtindex:index.row];`  The app will crash.

Comment: @Tek How is you `vcblr` organized? Let's say you have two sections with items `section 0:(a,b,c)` and `section 1:(x,y)`, would `vcblr` contain `(a,b,c,x,y)`?

Comment: Thank you for you promptly help! vcblr is declared as NSMutableArray in the AppDelegate.h. This array is also transfer from JSON array: `NSArray *vocabulary_ = [json objectForKey:@"vocabulary"];` `self.vcblr=[NSArray arrayWithArray:vocabulary_];` in the AppDelegate. The part of 'section' log like following: (
        (
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday,
        Saturday,
        Sunday
    ),
        (
        bike,
        bus,
        car,
        train,
        taxi
    ))

Comment: @Tek Then your `vcblr` is really an array of arrays, so your code `[[delegate.vcblr objectAtIndex:index.section]objectAtindex:index.row]` should have worked. If it is organized precisely like `self.sections` array from your master controller, double-indexing should be fine. Run in the debugger, set a breakpoint, and look at the structure of your array in Xcode.

Comment: The console window will show following info: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a73e80'. I have checked some similar posts in this site and want to know is it neecessary to add `if (indexPath.section == __) ` condition statements in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: @Tek "unrecognized selector" error means that an object is not of the type that you think it is. This almost certainly means that `vcblr` is not an array of arrays. Check its structure, make sure it's an array of arrays, and that the number of items in each dimension is correct, and it's going to work.

Comment: You do me a big favor exactly. By your suggestion, I had modified vcblr array structure and could use the double index method to access particular element in the array. Than you so much!