# Reference to object returns null (iOS class inheritance)

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, inheritance

I am new to iOS programming and  having some issues with class inheritance.

I have a class with an object (initialized as a property in .h)

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSNumber *count;
```

It increments for every button pressed in a certain function.

In another class I reference it:

```
#import "otherClass.h"
...
otherClass *otherC = [[otherClass alloc]init];
NSLog(@"COUNT: %@", otherClass.count);
```

No matter how I try, the output remains null. I'm not sure if I'm implementing it wrong. Please help!

**Found Solution

(1) Define a new class, call it RSModel (2) Move @property (nonatomic) NSInteger count into that new class, along with the instance method that you defined. The instance method needs to change to return RSModel (3) In all view controllers where you need to access the count, include "RSModel.h", and write [RSModel instance].count to access the shared counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a property `weak`, it means that there exists at least one strong reference to the same object, which keeps it from being released. It does not look like that's what is happening in your case. Moreover, it does not look like you need `NSNumber` there - `NSInteger` should be sufficient. In this case, you wouldn't need to worry about the weak/strong distinction:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger count;

...
therClass *otherC = [[otherClass alloc]init];
NSLog(@"COUNT: %d", otherClass.count);
```

Note, however, that since `count` is an instance property, the incrementing needs to happen on the same instance of your `otherClass`. All new objects of that class would have their `count` property set to the default value of zero.

Comment: The problem is that i have to show the count in a different view(showing a sort of 'activity log'), which requires a different class(as far as I know, and I'm not using storyboard) is there any way to save the count value elsewhere to pass it/for the other class to get the value at all?

Comment: @jcaso Absolutely, there is! Make a singleton object with your counter ([here is how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11945106/335858)), instantiate it once, and keep using it from all of your controllers.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me an example with my code? I'm still a little confused on how to use this to access the counter :X

Comment: @jcaso Did you follow the example from the link in my previous comment? Please update your code with the results of your change, and I'll help you fix it.

Comment: I just included it in my original question above. I'm just not sure what to do with it

Comment: @jcaso Excellent, that's a good start! Here is what you need to do: (1) Define a new class, call it `RSModel` (2) Move `@property (nonatomic) NSInteger count` into that new class, along with the `instance` method that you defined. The `instance` method needs to change to return `RSModel` (3) In all view controllers where you need to access the count, include `"RSModel.h"`, and write `[RSModel instance].count` to access the shared counter. This should do the trick.

Comment: One more thing - I did the same for an NSString, and would like to set it to a label. When I do [ActivityLogText setText:log] (where log = [RSModel instance].activityLogString) the label does not change. Do I have to do something differently?

Comment: @jcaso This should work as well. However, the timing of this needs to be right: you need to do it when the visuals are already created (e.g. in `viewWillAppear`) ans the `activityLogString` has been set.

Comment: Ahh I was just setting something wrong in the .xib file, I got it. Thank you again so much.

Answer (score 3):

By declaring your `@property` as weak you are saying that someone else owns that object, and if nothing else is pointing to it, to automatically deallocate it and set it to nil.  I'm guessing this isn't what you wanted to do.  Try changing it to this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *count;
```