# Pass data between same view controller class

Tags: ios, segue

I've start learning iOS development (with Objective-C) and I'm having the following problem.

**What I did so far:**

I want to divide the registration process into a number of view controllers. For example:

- View controller 1 has fields for `fname` and `lname`.
- View controller 2 has a field for `email`.
- View controller 3 has a field for `password` and a "save" button.

Now, I created a new `UIViewController` class file named `RegistrationViewController` and assigned that class to all view controllers above, so that I can write all registration-related code in a one file.

I've used a push segue to get to the next view controller from the current view controller.

**ISSUE**

When I click the "save" button on the last view controller, I'm not able to get the values for `fname`, `lname`, and `email`.

Why is that so? I mean, I'm in the same file. Shouldn't the value be stored for those properties?

Answer (score 1):

> I've used a push segue to get to the next viewcontroller form a viewcontoller.

Push segue pushes a brand-new instance of the view controller, meaning that the view controller currently on the top would have only the values set in itself, while values set in all of its predecessors would be `nil`.

You should not be relying on storing values in fields of your view controller. Instead, you should set them on the shared instance of your model class, as suggested by the Model-View-Controller design pattern:

```
class Model {
    static let sharedInstance = Model()
    var fName : String
    var lName : String
    ...
}
```

When you detect that the next view controller is about to open, store the state accumulated by the current one in the shared model object:

```
Model.sharedInstance.fName = self.fName
Model.sharedInstance.fName = self.lName
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. you are right using a shared instance is a right choice. Can you please just give me a simple idea about how to create a shared instance so that it can work for all those three viewcontollers. I've created a new "AllUsers.h" (NSObject) class file.

Comment: I'm using an objective-c language.

Comment: @Jimmy I'm sorry I missed the Objective-C part. [Here is a Q&A with an example of using singleton model in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11945106/335858). It is considerably more complex, but it is essentially a copy-paste exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Just because data is in the "same file" doesn't mean anything to the app at runtime. You're still creating multiple separate instances of your `RegistrationViewController` class. Therefore, you'll need to pass data between these separate instances, the same way you would for completely different classes.

Since you're using storyboards and segues, the method `-prepareForSegue:sender:` is a good place to look into doing that.

---

For the record, I agree with @dasblinkenlight's suggestion to store this data in a model object instead of individual fields, but disagree with using a "shared instance" if you don't have to. An example of passing a model object would look like this:

**User.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fname;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lname;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
```

**RegistrationViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) User *user;
```

**RegistrationViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    RegistrationViewController *nextViewController = (RegistrationViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    nextViewController.user = self.user;
}

- (IBAction)doSaveAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog("email: %@", self.user.email;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've used shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier, coz I want to perform validation before continue to next view controller.

Comment: Ideally, you should use _both_. `-shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` doesn't provide you with the actual segue, and therefore doesn't provide you with your destination view controller in order to pass data to it.

Comment: is shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier is called before -prepareForSegue method?

Comment: Do you think the set up I did for what i want, is not right? I mean, would it be standard practice to creat a new class file for each viewcontoller. If you were in place of me and wanted to do the same thing. What will be your approach. - Thank you

Comment: Eh, now you're getting into hairy questions of software architecture that are above and beyond the scope of this question. But in general, yes, I would probably have split these up into three separate view controller classes.

Comment: Yes, `-shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` is called before `-prepareForSegue:`. If you return `NO` from `-shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:`, `-prepareForSegue:` will not be called at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions and coding. I'll try that and let you know. Also Sorry for asking a question which was beyond the scope.

Comment: Where do I need to alloc]init the USER obj? If I do it in registrationViewController's viewDidLoad. I think it will get override everytime. isn't it?

Comment: It's not working, can you please help? I did self.user = [[USER allco]init]; in viewDidLoad and that is why it create a new object everytime the view loads and delete the old values. Which is a right place do it?